# BS4 не может найти контент с meta тега

Tags: python, requests, bs4

Не могу получить csrf токен с meta тега, раньше всё работало.

Сам код:

```py
    def get_csrf(link):
        response = sess.get(url=link, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
        csrf = soup.find("meta", attrs={'name': "csrf-token", 'type': "hidden"})
        print(csrf["content"])
        return csrf["content"]
```

Ошибка:

```py
    print(csrf["content"])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Сайт какой? Что в response_code? Может Вы бан получили уже?

Comment: 200 response_code

Comment: Значит либо на сайте что-то поменялось, либо выкидывает на robots, там тоже 200 будет. Есть смысл посмотреть что внутри `soup`, вывести через `print`. Ну и что за сайт если напишите, можно будет более предметно обсудить.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Y3NzbTYK - внутренность soup`a 

Сайт - https://naurok.com.ua/test/kontrolna-robota-opracyuvannya-tablichnih-danih-1926273/set но там надо зарегистрироваться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в теге meta нету типа hidden и по этому ничего не находило

Comment: Ну вот, иногда полезно в переменную soup заглянуть 

Answer (score 0):

можно получать данные по ключу

```
csrf = soup.find("meta")['csrf-token']
```

Comment: сейчас проверю.
Новая ошибка:
KeyError: 'csrf-token'